# make image responsive based on window height when width is constant

Tags: html, css

Sample on CodePen: http://codepen.io/seadrag0n/pen/oxVJgX

I am learning responsive design without using libraries like `bootstrap` and I am facing issue when showing large images in a popup which should be both height and width responsive. I have the following snippet:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.outer {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  max-width: 1200px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
}

.inner {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
}

.inner img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto!important;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <img src="http://www.cameraegg.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/Sony-RX100-IV-Sample-Images-2.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Using the above markup, the image is `width` responsive but it not `height` responsive and in screens of `1920 x 1080` resolution the image looks fine but when I switch to a `1366 x 768` resolution, the image overflow instead of adjusting to the screen size. How can I solve this?

I want to achieve the same styling as it is done in [this](http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/#lg=1&slide=1) plugin, if you keep width the same and reduce height of the browser window, the image adjusts to the screen size even though the width is the same.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575141/make-div-100-height-of-browser-window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/cq0Lqqes/)

Just use `height 100vh`

```css
.outer {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  max-width: 1200px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
}

.inner {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
}

.inner img {
  height: 100vh;
  max-width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <img src="https://c7.staticflickr.com/3/2538/3742771246_2648fa4e6e_b.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the image is no longer width responsive with `height: 100vh`, it is getting stretched when i reduce width..how to fix this in your css? I want the image to be both height and width responsive

Comment: height remains the same if I reduce browser width and the image is getting stretched in the fiddle

Comment: so what what is meant by responsive height and width in your case

Comment: http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/#lg=1&slide=0 check this link, reduce either height or width or both of your browser window and you will see that the image adjusts perfectly while maintaining the aspect ratio..

Answer (score 0):

Check this CodePen: http://codepen.io/uzumakinaruto1/pen/QNozyr

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.outer {
  max-width: 1200px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
}

.inner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.inner img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <img src="http://www.cameraegg.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/Sony-RX100-IV-Sample-Images-2.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the image is not maintaining aspect ratio when reducing window width..the image should be both height and width responsive